# How to align my navbar dropdown list with the rest of my navbar links?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little trouble aligning my navbar's dropdown list ("Links") with the rest of the links on the navbar.

This is one of my first projects so I'm a little confused as to where I should be editing my current code so it lines up correctly. Any help???

Here's a screenshot of the issue:
[image]

[image]
Obviously what I'm actually expecting/trying to do is to line up the 'Links' dropdown button with the rest of the navbar links.

If anybody could help it would be appreciated!

```css
/* Navbar Container */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
}


/* Navbar Links */

.navbar a {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Links Container */

.links {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Links Button */

.links .linksbutton {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}


/* Hover Color */

.navbar a:hover,
.links:hover .linksbutton {
  background-color: red;
}


/* Dropdown Content */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Dropdown Links */

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Dropdown Links Hover Color */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show Dropdown Menu on Hover */

.links:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#about-us">About Us</a>
  <a href="#music">Music</a>
  <a href="#discography">Discography</a>
  <div class="links">
    <button class="linksbutton">Links</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="https://tru-thoughts.co.uk/artists/quantic/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Tru Thoughts</a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/quanticmusic/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Facebook</a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/quanticmusic/?hl=en" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Instagram</a>
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_Holland" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Wikipedia</a>
      <a href="https://quanticmusic.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"> Bandcamp</a>
      <a href="https://www.discogs.com/artist/161443-Will-Holland" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Discogs</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide the HTML in addition to your CSS so we can see your dom structure.

Comment: This information is not enough, could you please provide a better screenshot,  as I can see there are not any screenshots, also provide html code also.

Comment: @RowanBaker-French Apologies, that was sloppy. I've edited to include the HTML and additional screenshots. Thanks

Comment: @GreatKT Apologies, I've edited in a couple of extra screenshots and the HTML for the navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the content inside your navbar into `flexbox` and center it vertically.

Try this:

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make float: "left" for `<a></a>` links and `<div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
overflow:hidden;
```

from your links class.